# Lucene Parallel search

Tags: java, search, lucene, executorservice

I have built an index of about 50M documents (these documents are very short). I also have about 1M query I want to run over the index. Sequentially picking a query and running it over the index is straightforward but very slow.

I've tried to parallelize the search (which is still slow) and ran multiple searchers over the index which is already in RAM. It still did not improve performance so I wonder if parallel search is supported by Lucene or if there is an efficient way of doing it by considering that the Index is in memory.

Comment: Why do you have to run a million query? If you are trying to find similarity between terms then there are other ways of doing it. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: No. Not similarity. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How do you know that your index is in RAM? Are you using [`Lucene’s MMapDirectory`](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2012/07/use-lucenes-mmapdirectory-on-64bit.html)?

Also, are you opening [`IndexReader` with `readOnly=true`](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed)?

By the way, avoid using `RAMDirectory` as it [puts a heavy load on your GC](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/07/lucene-index-in-ram-with-azuls-zing-jvm.html).